# How detect when user use clipboard feature in Keyboard (like gboard)

Tags: flutter

I have a pin code with 4 text fields.

The user can paste in any of them.

I can retrieve the paste via the context menu.

I don't know how to retrieve the paste when the user uses the shortcut on the keyboard () before it's pasted into my text field.

[image: gboard]

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the copied clipboard data globally, without being tied to text fields, you should use this function:
`await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);`

If I understood correctly, your solution should look something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: PinCodePage(),
    );
  }
}

class PinCodePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PinCodePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<PinCodePage> createState() => _PinCodePageState();
}

class _PinCodePageState extends State<PinCodePage> {
  // Create a list of text editing controllers, one for each pin code field.
  final _controllers = List.generate(4, (_) => TextEditingController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Listen for changes in each text field to handle pastes.
    for (final controller in _controllers) {
      controller.addListener(() {
        _handlePaste(controller);
      });
    }
  }

  void _handlePaste(TextEditingController controller) async {
    // Get the current content of the clipboard.
    final data = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
    // Check if the clipboard data is exactly 4 characters long.
    final text = data?.text;
    if (text == null || text.length < 2) return;
    // If so, distribute the characters across the four text fields.
    for (int i = 0; i < _controllers.length; i++) {
      final chart = text.characters.elementAtOrNull(i);

      if (chart == null) return;

      _controllers[i].text = chart;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final controller in _controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pin Code Input'),
      ),
      // Generate the text fields for pin code input.
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: _controllers.map((controller) {
            return Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                // Configure each text field.
                child: TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                  maxLength: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(counterText: ""),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want. Your solution automatically retrieves text from the clipboard. I want to retrieve the text the moment he presses the paste shortcut on the keyboard.